# Raspberry Pi script: run couple of command line if not able to ping IP?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I need reconnect to VPN if it had disconnected. I suggest following simple script

```
BEGING:
    WHILE (PING XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX == SUCCESSFULL)
    {
       SLEEP (10 SEC)
    }

    SUDO POP <SERVER> 

GO TO: BEGINING
```

I was considering to do this with Node.JS, but maybe there is better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

A cron job for a bash script would seem reasonable.

Comment: I don't know who to write such script.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, a script that will execute on a cron. If you are using Raspbian, and new to linux, there is a nice doc on editing the crontab here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Comment: crontab are script runner, but I need script itself.

Comment: So learn basic shell scripting? Or pay a sysadmin to write it for you? This is not a code-writing-service.